# Drop Down & Picture Box integration

Tags: vb6

I have a simple form with a drop down box with a list of names in it 
and a picture box above that .

how can i make it when i select a name the picture 
of that person shows up automatically in the picture box ?

Comment: You’ve put three different VB dialects in the tags. Which one are you actually interested in? Please don’t add irrelevant tags.

Comment: No apologies needed, but tags removal will be useful.

Comment: i can get it to work by putting the image's file path in the combo box but when you clck the combo box to select a person it just shows C:\filename etc . any help would be great

Comment: You need some way to associate the file with the person's name.

Answer (score 0):

use a user defined type containing both the name as well as the picture file, and then create an array of this type

for example :

```
'1 form with :
'    1 listbox : name=List1
'    1 picturebox : name=Picture1
Option Explicit

Private Type PERSON
  strName As String
  strPicture As String
End Type

Private mperFriend(4) As PERSON

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  mperFriend(0).strName = "Bob"
  mperFriend(0).strPicture = "Bob.jpg"
  mperFriend(1).strName = "Jane"
  mperFriend(1).strPicture = "Jane.jpg"
  mperFriend(2).strName = "Fred"
  mperFriend(2).strPicture = "Fred.jpg"
  mperFriend(3).strName = "Iris"
  mperFriend(3).strPicture = "Iris.jpg"
  mperFriend(4).strName = "John"
  mperFriend(4).strPicture = "John.jpg"
  List1.Clear
  For intIndex = 0 To UBound(mperFriend)
    List1.AddItem mperFriend(intIndex).strName
  Next intIndex
End Sub

Private Sub List1_Click()
  Caption = mperFriend(List1.ListIndex).strPicture
  Picture1.Picture = LoadPicture(App.Path & "\" & mperFriend(List1.ListIndex).strPicture)
End Sub
```